# I need some guidance and help from pros to host my new app .(please read everything)

Tags: hosting

I have been making Desktop applications for last few years. but now i have quite that job and thinking about doing working for myself. I have gone through many ideas. finally i decided to develop Online billing application . Since i am new in web application i know very little about web technologies.

I am thinking about developing that application in php or asp.net with mysql database. I don't know which one is better.(you can guide me here). I don't know whether its good idea or not.but i don't want to do job and work for myself that's for sure.

its going to be a big project so I was making budget for this whole project but i don't know what kind of hosting i will need for this app because database load will be very high because its billing application. i don't know how much it will cost me.I will give user free trial for 30 days to use application and if they like they can upgrade their accounts.

So i need your help to decide what kind of hosting will be appropriate.is this ok if i use webhosting that we use to host website which will cost me $10 to $15 a month or i will have to use cloud hosting which will cost me a lot?

I hope this link will give you idea. I want to make application like this :    http://www.rapid-billing.com .

pls help me out. it might me small things for you but to me it matters a lot. Thanks

Comment: The part about php vs asp is too subjective for SO.

Comment: thank you for responding ...but ..its not programmning language i am worried about but its hosting that i am worried about. i want to make application like this http://www.rapid-billing.com . where to host this and how much will it cost.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you won't have very high traffic, so using a cheap, shared server should be fine. If you outgrow it, then you must have some money coming in, so the added expense of cloud hosting will be more tolerable. There's no need to go all-in before you even get going.

That said, many cloud hosts offer some amount of hosting free, which would probably suit you just as well during initial development. An added plus of starting in the cloud is that you won't have to migrate later. Off the top of my head, [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) and [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) come to mind as well-known cloud hosts with a free tier. [Microsoft Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/) also provides a free 3 month trial, and I imagine they'd be a good host if you choose to go with ASP.

Comment: you answer is great help to me. i have almost got my answer.since you are already in cloud hosting business , you must be knowing more.Is this ok if make the same site like   http://www.rapid-billing.com .. is there any chance i will succeed? or i should make desktop application with same functionality? pls guide me ..thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to launch a business that already has a direct, established competitor, you have to ask yourself what you will do better. To put it another way, why would a customer choose your billing service over rapid-billing.com? These are the sort of things  you have to consider before you start putting time and money into a project like this.

Comment: i will give it cheap..i think that will distinguish me